# How to take first 2 element in for loop then skip the third element java

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a row of arraylist data that looks like this

```
JANUARY | DAY1 | ABSENT | MC | DAY2 | ABSENT| MC | DAY3 |ACTIVE| - | DAY4 |ACTIVE | - |
FEBRUARY| DAY1 | ACTIVE |    | DAY2 | ABSENT| MC | DAY3 |ACTIVE| - | DAY4 |ACTIVE | - |
MARCH   | DAY1 | ABSENT | MC | DAY2 | ACTIVE| -  | DAY3 |ACTIVE| - | DAY4 |ACTIVE | - |
```

or in a form of arraylist would be like this,

```
[JANUARY,DAY1,ABSENT,MC,DAY2,ABSENT,MC,DAY3,ACTIVE,-,DAY4,ACTIVE,]
[FEBRUARY,DAY1,ACTIVE ,-,DAY2,ABSENT,MC,DAY3,ACTIVE,-,DAY4,ACTIVE,]
[MARCH,DAY1,ABSENT,MC,DAY2,ACTIVE,-,DAY3,ACTIVE,-,DAY4,ACTIVE,-]
```

So intstead of store all the data, What I want to achieve here is I want to store only the data after the column DAY1, DAY2, DAY3,DAY4 which like this:

```
[ABSENT,MC,ABSENT,MC,ACTIVE,-,ACTIVE,-]
[ACTIVE,-,ABSENT,MC,ACTIVE,-,ACTIVE,-]
[ABSENT,MC,ABSENT,MC,ACTIVE,-,ACTIVE,]
```

my current code looks like this for the looping:

```
    DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();

        String val = null;

        for (int rowNum = 1; rowNum < sheet.getLastRowNum(); rowNum++) {
            Row r = sheet.getRow(rowNum);

            ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();


            for (int i = 2; i+2 < r.getLastCellNum() + 1; i = i + 3) {
                Cell cell = r.getCell(i);
                val = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
                al.add(val);
            }

            System.out.println(al);
        }
```

but this will result only the first element which is ABSENT. it still missing the next element of it. please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add first element and second element inside for loop.

```
DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();

    String val = null;

    for (int rowNum = 1; rowNum < sheet.getLastRowNum(); rowNum++) {
        Row r = sheet.getRow(rowNum);

        ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();


        for (int i = 2; i+2 < r.getLastCellNum() + 1; i = i + 3) {
            Cell cell = r.getCell(i);
            val = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
            al.add(val);
            cell = r.getCell(i+1);
            val = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
            al.add(val);
        }

        System.out.println(al);
    }
```

Comment: thank you Sir for helping me. this work like a charm

Comment: Glad that I am able to help. Please mark it as answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ignore the first and DAY columns

```
for (int i = 1; i < r.getLastCellNum(); i++) {
    Cell cell = r.getCell(i);
    String val = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
    if (!val.startsWith("DAY")) {
        al.add(val);
    }
}
```